# I keep getting an "invalid type (list) for variable" error in R but none of my variables are lists

Tags: r, linear-regression, spotify

I was trying to build an additive model for my spotifyr project but kept getting the "invalid type (list) for variable" when I tried to run my model. Here's what I did:

```
 library(spotifyr)
Sys.setenv(SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
Sys.setenv(SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
access_token <- get_spotify_access_token()
```

Accessed my data:

```
playlist_uri_2 <- c('37i9dQZF1DX7yD3GiuEB7x')
dreamcatcher <- get_playlist_audio_features(playlist_username, playlist_uri_2)
View(dreamcatcher)
```

Removed duplicates and unnecessary columns:

```
dreamcatcher_tidy <- dreamcatcher[-c(31:32, 70, 75:79, 80, 82), ]
View(dreamcatcher_tidy)
dream_stat_tidy <- dreamcatcher_tidy[ -c(1,3,4:5, 17:18, 20:30, 32:35, 38:48, 51:58)]
View(dream_stat_tidy)
```

And started to build my model:

```
dance_stat <- lm(tempo ~ danceability, data = dream_stat_tidy)
summary(dream_dance) 

energy_stat <- lm(tempo ~ energy, data = dream_stat_tidy)
summary(dream_energy) 

add <- lm(tempo ~ dance_stat + energy_stat, data = dream_stat_tidy)
summary(add)
```

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = tempo ~ dream_dance + dream_energy,  :
> invalid type (list) for variable 'dream_dance'

I then tried to see if any of my variables were lists.

```
class(dream_stat_tidy$danceability) #numeric
str(dream_stat_tidy$danceability)

class(dream_stat_tidy$tempo) #numeric
str(dream_stat_tidy$tempo) 

class(dream_stat_tidy$energy) #numeric
str(dream_stat_tidy$energy) 

class(energy_stat) #lm
str(energy_stat) 

class(dance_stat) #lm
str(dance_stat)
```

None of my variables were lists but I tried unlisting the variables anyway to see what would happen; it did nothing. I'm stuck and not sure how to make my model work.

Comment: What are the classes of 'dream_dance' and 'dream_energy' - these are not actually shown in your example code, but are the ones causing the error.

Comment: In the last formula, `tempo ~ dance_stat + energy_stat`, the regressors are lists. They are the output of the two previous `lm` instructions, a function which returns a list of class `"lm"`.

Comment: @randr Oops! Typed it wrong. 'dream_dance' is the same as 'dance_stat' and 'dream_energy' is the same as 'energy_stat'.

Comment: @RuiBarradas how do I fix this? unlist() does not work.

Comment: The right formula is `tempo ~ danceability + energy`. With the same regressors as the previous models.